# Hibernate, how to build query joining multiple tables at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, builder

I have one parent table and many children tables (say 5). Based on the input parameter, I would choose the number of children tables with parent to fetch result. Joining the number of children tables with parent table is decide on run time parameter. The number of table joined in the query may be one to 5.
I would implement using Hibernate ORM, please suggest me better approaches to achieve it.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: an option should be defining fetches in your service method and send this fetchList  as parameter to your dao method and adding them in a loop inside your criteria. After that you will have so many joins as fetch you did specify before.

Comment: You can form your hql query at runtime based on your input parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I have parent entity and having all the child entities mapped onetomany and manytoone in parent/child classes respectively. please provide me details how i can join only those child entities based on parameter.